# JavaScript color parser

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I was wondering how i could use regex to create a span element  when the text ^1 was found and group the text after that and enclose it in the created span element

The idea is that you have a chatbox and when ever someone submits a message for example like this: (without not having any significance)

" ^1Hello there ^3hows it goin.. "

would output as "Hello there" <- would be in red color "hows it goin.." <- would be in green color

The codes would be:

- ^1 - Red
- ^2 - black
- ^3 - green
- ^4 - yellow
- ^5 - blue
- ^6 - lightblue
- ^7 - purple
- ^8 - dark green
- ^9 - grey

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a site for asking for ready-made solutions to your problems, you're expected to attempt to solve the problem yourself, and post your attempt.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use RegEx for this.  Gets too messy having to worry about closing existing spans, replacing each numeric value with the appropriate color, and will be a nightmare to maintain.  Just parse by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use a regular expression. for example:

```
\^(\d+)([^^]+)
```

this matches a number preceded by a caret and anything after it until a new caret is found.